# SDK image not found when running OSX UI Tests with Cocoapods

Tags: macos, testing, cocoapods

I am trying to add my first automated UI tests to my application and am running into quite a bit of difficultly.

The app will build in its current state and the main application itself runs just fine. However, when I try to run my tests I get the following error:

```
2016-08-02 19:39:33.340 XCTRunner[17590:966857] Running tests...
2016-08-02 19:39:33.407 XCTRunner[17590:966857] The bundle “MYAPPUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2016-08-02 19:39:33.407 XCTRunner[17590:966857] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-bdpxtxtxmsobtreqnojvykobjlts/Build/Products/Debug/MYAPPUITests-Runner.app/Contents/PlugIns/MYAPPUITests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/MYAPPUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/A/HockeySDK
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-bdpxtxtxmsobtreqnojvykobjlts/Build/Products/Debug/MYAPPUITests-Runner.app/Contents/PlugIns/MYAPPUITests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/MYAPPUITests
  Reason: image not found)
```

I've seen that there are a few related questions on SO but none of them see to help me out.

Originally, I was implementing my tests in Swift on top of an Objective C application and thought that might be the problem. However, I discovered after making an Objective-C based test target that I am running into exactly the same issue in Objective C.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Some additional information: I have tried this using both Cocoapods 0.39.0 as well as the latest non-beta 1.x release. Both resulted in the same error.

My podfile is listed below (for 0.39.0)

```
platform :osx, '10.9'
link_with 'MYAPP', 'MYAPP MAS', 'MYAPPUITests'


pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.0'
pod 'ISO8601DateFormatter'
pod 'CDEvents', :git => 'https://github.com/rastersize/CDEvents'
pod 'MASShortcut', '1.3.1'
pod 'libPusher', '1.6'
pod 'NPReachability', :git => 'https://github.com/Abizern/NPReachability.git', :commit => 'e57753d'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'SocketRocket', :git => 'https://github.com/marianoabdala/SocketRocket.git'
pod 'HockeySDK-Mac'
pod 'INAppStoreWindow', '~> 1.4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this after spending 2-3 days on this by adding an obscure step to my Build Phases.

I created a `Copy Files` build step after the `Link Binary With Libraries` step and before the `Embed Pods Frameworks` step.

I copied the offending framework ("HockeySDK") into the Products Directory. This solved the issue!

Ultimately this may be related to my app being a StatusBar App, not a regular app, as the solution which finally worked for me was related to a CommandLine application running into the same bug.

[Link to Github bug page with the solution that worked for me](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/975)

[image: Screenshot of Build Phases I created to solve the problem]